# Do c++ values created in an initialization list go on the stack?

Tags: c++, memory-management, standards

In other words, is the following code valid?
-- It works with gcc 4.7, however, I am not sure is it in the standard or only implementation dependent.

```cpp
struct A {
    int data[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
};

struct B {
    B(int data[]) 
    ...

struct C : public B {
    C() 
        : B(A().data) 
    ...
```

Comment: It is impossible to say whether the code is correct or not without seeing what goes on inside the ellipsis. It will be correct or not depending on what you do with `data` inside `B::B`

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is misleading.

```
struct A {
    int data[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
};
```

A new feature of C++11, see [class.mem]: This syntax initializes the data member `data` during the construction of an object of type `A`. It has nothing to do with initializer-lists, it's a language feature (*list-initialization* using a *braced-init-list*).

It's equivalent to:

```
struct A {
    int data[3];
    inline A() : data{1,2,3}
    {}
};
```

Therefore, `data` is on the stack if you've created the instance of `A` on the stack, and it's on the heap if the instance has been created on the heap.

I guess where the data for initialization resides (= the `1,2,3`) is implementation-defined.

As [Michael Crawford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2368132/michael-crawford) points out, there might be issues with calling `B(int data[])` (which will be decayed to `B(int* data)`), but those don't necessarily make your program ill-formed (it should still compile).

---

As to passing `A().data` to the ctor of `B`:

`A()` creates a temporary object; its lifetime is specified in [class.temporary]/3

> Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.

Using them in the *mem-initializer-list* is no exception; the full-expression is `B::B( A().data )`. As this full-expression includes the ctor of `B`, the temporary introduced by `A()` and with it the data member `data` are destroyed only after the the ctor `B::B` has been executed.

Comment: Dear @DyP, I am speaking of this ` : B(A().data)` initialization list. The B constructor is also what I meant. I do want to know, does the data constructed here ` : B(A().data)`, are pushed on stack and still alive inside the B constructor.

Comment: @Number47 It's called a *mem-initializer-list* in the Standard, initializer-lists are `std::initializer_list<type>` there ;)

Comment: Thanks. It isn't easy to know everything precisely, about this behemoth. ;)

Answer (score 1):

the int data[] in B's initialization list is a pointer to the beginning of the array rather than the entire array.  That's probably not what you want.

However, if data were a Standard Template Library vector, you could use a copy constructor to copy the whole vector in a single initialization list item.

Comment: Yes, probably not what he wants... +1

Comment: Well, it indeed is what she wants. I am not interested in coping the data, but rather passing them to the B constructor for the time of the construction.